# Problems with upgrading from 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 23.10

I'm trying to upgrade from 23.04 to 23.10 right after upgrading from 22.04 LTS. During the upgrade, I get this error:

> ##### Could not calculate the upgrade
>
> [...]
> This was likely caused by:
> * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu.
> [...]

The error dialogue looks like this (image from [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/j02f80/hi_i_was_updating_from_ubuntu_1804_to_2004_and/)):

[image: error screenshot]

I have investigated `/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log` and I found:

```
WARNING Can't mark 'ubuntu-desktop' for upgrade(E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.)
```

So I ran this:

```
apt-mark showhold
```

I have run `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` and it installed a bunch of stuff. Same symptoms afterwards though.

I've also tried the following commands:

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/lunar/mantic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-remote-desktop : Depends: libmutter-12-0 (>= 44~) but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-shell : Depends: gir1.2-mutter-12 (>= 44.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libmutter-12-0 (>= 44.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Here are some useful outputs:

- Output of `apt-cache policy ubuntu-desktop`

  ```
  ubuntu-desktop:
    Installed: 1.501
    Candidate: 1.501
   *** 1.501 500
          500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/main amd64 Packages
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  ```
- Output of `apt-cache policy gnome-remote-desktop libmutter-12-0 gnome-shell gir1.2-mutter-12 libmutter-12-0`:

  ```
  gnome-remote-desktop:
    Installed: 44.2-0ubuntu1
    Candidate: 45.0-1
    Version table:
       45.0-1 500
          500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 Packages
   *** 44.2-0ubuntu1 100
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  libmutter-12-0:
    Installed: 44.3-0ubuntu1.1
    Candidate: 44.3-0ubuntu1.1
    Version table:
   *** 44.3-0ubuntu1.1 100
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  gnome-shell:
    Installed: 44.3-0ubuntu1.1
    Candidate: 45.1-0ubuntu1
    Version table:
       45.1-0ubuntu1 500
          500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates/main amd64 Packages
       45.0-1ubuntu2 500
          500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic/main amd64 Packages
   *** 44.3-0ubuntu1.1 100
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  gir1.2-mutter-12:
    Installed: 44.3-0ubuntu1.1
    Candidate: 44.3-0ubuntu1.1
    Version table:
   *** 44.3-0ubuntu1.1 100
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  libmutter-12-0:
    Installed: 44.3-0ubuntu1.1
    Candidate: 44.3-0ubuntu1.1
    Version table:
   *** 44.3-0ubuntu1.1 100
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  ```
- Output of `grep ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`:

  ```
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/1password.list:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/1password-archive-keyring.gpg] https://downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable main
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/1password.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/1password-archive-keyring.gpg] https://downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable main
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/1password.list.save:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/1password-archive-keyring.gpg] https://downloads.1password.com/linux/debian/amd64 stable main
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list.save:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   jammy stable
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   jammy stable
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list.save:deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu   jammy stable
  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list.save:deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ lunar main # disabled on upgrade to lunar
  ```
- Output of `grep ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list`:

  ```
  deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic main restricted
  deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic-updates main restricted
  deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic universe
  deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic-updates universe
  deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic multiverse
  deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic-updates multiverse
  deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ mantic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security main restricted
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security universe
  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security multiverse
  ```

I feel I'm lost here. What to do next?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect (as indicated by the screenshot) you have some PPAs enabled which are holding things back. One brutal way to figure out what that is, is to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to replace `lunar` with `mantic` then `sudo apt update ; sudo apt dist-upgrade`, but *don't* say 'y' to do the upgrade. Then see what errors you get. Paste those in the question.

It's possible at that point to revert the `sources.list` file and do another `apt update` to go back, assuming you didn't upgrade any packages.

It's also *possible* to actually do the full release upgrade this way. But it will likely fail, given the pre-flight checks that `update-manager` or `do-release-upgrade` are showing, suggest it won't work.

It could leave you with a non-functioning desktop - for example booting to a black screen with no desktop.

Personally speaking, I'd force the upgrade with a `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, and if any packages fail, with the messages you've seen, I'd force install the specific packages e.g. `sudo apt install gnome-shell gnome-remote-desktop`.

It might require running `sudo apt dist-upgrade` a second time, and even `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^`. I would not reboot until you can get apt to be happy with `dist-upgrade` and installing `ubuntu-desktop^`. But this is your system. You may want to wait for a better answer :)